# Is there a convenience function in win32 (windows.h) that would convert lParam to POINT?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, point

I keep doing the following:

```
LRESULT OnMouseMove(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled) {
    mouse.x = LOWORD(lParam);
    mouse.y = HIWORD(lParam);
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

I wonder if there is a convenience method that will convert `LOWORD(lParam)` and `HIWORD(lParam)` to a `Point` for me? So I could do something like `mouse = ToPoint(lParam)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but it would be trivial to roll your own:

```
POINT ToPoint(LPARAM lParam)
{
  POINT p={GET_X_LPARAM(lParam),GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam)};

  return p;
}
```

Comment: The `WM_MOUSEMOVE` documentation clearly states that `LOWORD`/`HIWORD` should not be used to get the coordinates.

Comment: Here I go, spending my hard earned rep just because people are too lazy to read documentation. I would be grateful if you simply deleted the misleading advice.

Comment: I think you guys should take away your downvotes; he changed the `LOWORD`/`HIWORD` to `GET_X_LPARAM`/`GET_Y_LPARAM`.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`GET_X_LPARAM()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632654.aspx) and [`GET_Y_LPARAM()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632655.aspx), or [`MAKEPOINTS()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145043.aspx), like the [`WM_MOUSEMOVE` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645616.aspx) says to:

> Use the following code to obtain the horizontal and vertical position:
>
> xPos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam);
>
> yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
>
> As noted above, the x-coordinate is in the low-order **short** of the return value; the y-coordinate is in the high-order **short** (both represent *signed* values because they can take negative values on systems with multiple monitors). If the return value is assigned to a variable, you can use the `MAKEPOINTS` macro to obtain a `POINTS` structure from the return value. You can also use the `GET_X_LPARAM` or `GET_Y_LPARAM` macro to extract the x- or y-coordinate.
>
> **Important**  Do not use the `LOWORD` or `HIWORD` macros to extract the x- and y- coordinates of the cursor position because these macros return incorrect results on systems with multiple monitors. Systems with multiple monitors can have negative x- and y- coordinates, and **LOWORD** and **HIWORD** treat the coordinates as unsigned quantities.

Comment: Wow... I didn't know about not using LOWORD and HIWORD. I just converted my code to use GET_X_LPARAM and GET_Y_LPARAM. Thanks!

Comment: @bodacydo The issues with `LOWORD`/`HIWORD` usually never become apparent with `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages since the coordinates are passed as client coordinates. As such they will never be less than zero. Until you use [`SetCapture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646262.aspx) and suddenly things get strange. @Remy I believe the documentation you quoted is inaccurate. In particular, client coordinates are always >= 0, regardless of where a window is. What do you think?

Comment: @Tim: the coordinates are relative to the client area of the window that receives the message. Negative coordinates can be reported during capturing. A window can capture the mouse and receive negative coordinates when the mouse moves to the left and/or above the capturing window. Try it for yourself. Take any UI control, have it call `SetCapture()` on itself for `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, call `ReleaseCapture()` for `WM_LBUTTONUP`, and log the coordinates that `WM_MOUSEMOVE` receives. Now run it, hold down the left mouse button on the control, and move the mouse around outside of the control.

Comment: @Remy Exactly, as I pointed out above, `SetCapture` is the only way that could make `WM_MOUSEMOVE` coordinates become negative. The documentation however keeps repeating the phrase *systems with multiple monitors*, which has nothing to do with `WM_MOUSEMOVE` coordinates becoming negative.

Comment: @Tim: The same wording appears in the [`GetMessagePos()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644938.aspx) documentation.  Multiple monitors is more relevant to that. So they probably just copy/pasted it.

Answer (score 5):

Use `CPoint`, like `CPoint p(lParam);`

Comment: Not sure I understand the downvotes... you all do realize that there's a convenience constructor for CPoint that converts LPARAM to the correct x/y components, don't you?  And that CPoint is just a nice wrapper for POINT?

Comment: Yes, we are clued in, thank you. However, since the question is tagged winapi and not MFC I took the freedom to downvote as it does not address the question. With that newly gained insight I would appreciate if you simply deleted the non-answer and give back the reputation I had to spend on you.

Comment: Well 1) OP asked about `Point` which wasn't clear if that meant `POINT` or `CPoint`... and 2) the use of `OnMouseMove` suggested the use of ATL.  Since `CPoint` is in the "Classes Shared by MFC and ATL" as per Microsoft, it seemed like a valid suggestion.

Comment: Your answer does not even attempt to state that it has different platform requirements from those stated in the question. As such a score < 0 is appropriate.

Comment: this is surely a good answer. might need some editing, but the info is pretty valid.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly but there is [`GET_X_LPARAM()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632654%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the corresponding for Y.

Comment: Yes, and this is clearly stated in the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` documentation. There is also a `MAKEPOINTS()` macro.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Documentation says that MAKEPOINTS returns a pointer to the POINT structure. Do I've to `free()` this pointer after I've used it?

Comment: @bodacydo: Read the documentation again more carefully. `MAKEPOINTS()` does NOT return a pointer, and the documentation does NOT say that it does. `MAKEPOINTS()` returns an actual `POINTS` structure instead: `POINTS point = MAKEPOINTS(lParam);`.

Comment: I see, there are two different structures `POINT` and `POINTS`, one contains longs, the other shorts...